# Geowebcache re-projection

Tags: geowebcache, coordinate-system

I have one layer (raster geotiff image) published in geoserver with EPSG: 3011 projection. But I want this layer in EPSG 4326 projection for use it in google API web application. I have searched on web and get to know that Geowebcache can do this conversion by adding custom projection. I am not sure, if geowebcache will change the layer projection from EPSG: 3011 to EPSG: 4326. Is it possible in geowebcache? If yes, then, should i need to add custom projection with EPSG: 4326? and then assign that layer (layer with EPSG: 3011) to custom projection.

need brief answer as i am new to geowebcache.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I've used GeoWebCache, but it does support the standard WMS interface.  If you were to specify a projection using the WMS string, it should reproject the tile for you.

Alternatively, you can specify a custom projection type in a configuration file in the directory containing the cache.  Here is a link to define the configuration file (geowebcache.xml) [GeoWebCache Configuration](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/config.html#gwc-config)

Finally the EPSG cod that specifies the Google Projection is **EPSG:900913**.

Answer (score 0):

GeoWebCache can't reproject tiles (according to the developers [in this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/21250)). You'll need to use [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/), or, ideally, reproject your data and serve it in the other projection with GeoServer.

Comment: While technically correct, GeoWebCache can't reproject existing tiles, if Geoserver is being used to serve the tiles prior to caching, then Geoserver can serve the tiles in the desired projection prior to Geowebcache caching them.